# Save photo from camera or get a photo from gallery kills the app Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera

User has two choice,s one to save a photo from camera app and the other is to get a photo from gallery. I'm testing it, and I set it to image view and here is the code I used:

```
private void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result=Utility.checkPermission(getActivity());

                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask ="Take Photo";
                    if(result)
                        cameraIntent();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    userChoosenTask ="Choose from Library";
                    if(result)
                        galleryIntent();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }

    private void galleryIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
    }

    private void cameraIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }
    }


    private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo"))
                        cameraIntent();
                    else if(userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library"))
                        galleryIntent();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap bm=null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        imageview.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
```

The photo which is taken by the camera is saved to the phone , after choosing a photo from gallery or save photo taken by camera app my app is destroyed and this is my problem I want it to return to app so I can use the image I've got.

Utility.checkPermission code :

```
public class Utility {
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context)
    {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show logcat with error?

Comment: no error appeared the application closes immediately